# C# VSTO Outlook 2003 GetExchangeUser

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

in my Outlook 2007 addin this code opens modal dialog box about user details (method Details(0) open this dialog) and works good:

```cs
this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists["Global Address List"].AddressEntries["USER NAME"].GetExchangeUser().Details(0);
```

But in Outlook 2003, there is no `GetExchangeUser().Details(0);`

How to open modal dialog by **contact name**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found solution:

```cs
this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").AddressLists["Global Address List"].AddressEntries["USER NAME"].Details(0);
```

Comment: string emailAddress = Globals.ObjNS.AddressLists["Global Address List"].AddressEntries["USER NAME"].Details(0);

It says that it can't implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'. 
For you reference
[Globals.ObjOutlook = (Outlook._Application)HostApplication;
Globals.ObjNS = Globals.ObjOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");]

Please advice me on this. Thanks